# How can I use colored icons in Nautilus sidebar?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, nautilus, icons, colors

Does anybody know how to make Nautilus (ubuntu GNOME 14.04) use colored icons in its sidebar instead of the default black/white ones?

Comment: Its really annoying. You can use Dolphin which is from KDE, `apt install dolphin` and its nice with split panes and colored icons. Only flaw is the global theme doesnt apply to it :(